# gcloud ping attempt failure with performing a 'docker push'

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I get this error with my gclould preview docker push gcr.io/<project id>/<imagename> CONSISTENTLY.

Someone has already asked this question before and Jeffrey van Gogh suggested it may be intermittent connection issue and suggested the curl command to test. I ran the curl command and get 'true' as the answer.

[gcloud ping attempt failure with performing a 'docker pus'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202923/gcloud-ping-attempt-failure-with-performing-a-docker-pus/29237619#29237619)

Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using boot2docker?  We have seen issues previously with the boot2docker VM's timestamp getting out of whack and not accepting our certificate.

See: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/290

Comment: Yes, I am using boot2docker. There is no alternative other than the Vbox work around?

Comment: Not AFAIK.  You could always try rebooting or replacing the boot2docker vm, but that seems like overkill.  You could also try using "docker machine" in place of boot2docker, I believe there is a GCE driver for it.

Comment: I have created an instance inside gcloud itself and worked from there. It worked.